Can't login via Ubuntu desktop after creating a Vagrant VM
I am testing Vagrant on VirualBox. A VM was created successfully using Vagrantfile and I can do Vagrant ssh into it, however when I try to login via Desktop Environment, I am unable to do so.

Here's my Vagrantfile:
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "apavy/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64"
  config.vm.provider "vmware_desktop" do |v|
    v.gui = true
  end
  
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 2
    v.name = "my_vm"
    v.gui = true
    v.check_guest_additions = false
  end
end

I understand that the GUI login has been changed from password based to a pub/private key based login, but I have no idea how can I set it up.

This issue is now resolved on my own after doing some more research. It appears that when Vagrant creates an Ubuntu 24.04 VM on VirtualBox, the default keyboard is set to "fr". The solution is to edit /etc/default/keyboard and change the contents like below, save the file, and reboot the system. After the reboot I was able to login to user vagrant with password as vagrant.
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="intl"
XKBOPTIONS=""

It looks like the Keyboard issue is only with the apavy/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64 image specifically where the default Keyboard language is set to "fr". I have tried other images and they work just fine with vagrant/vagrant.
